# BlackBerry: TreeField with BitmapField

Tags: blackberry, treeview, bitmapimage, treefield

I want to display the contacts in a [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html) like:

An image followed by a username

My understanding is that I use a **BitmapField** to display the image, but I don't see how to combine a **BitmapField** with a [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use another field with a TreeField.  You need to implement the TreeFieldCallback.drawTreeItem() method and do the drawing yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `graphics.drawBitmap()` method and `graphics.drawText()` method and using the index and y parameters inside the drawTreeItem() method of class which implements `TreeFieldCallback` interface

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to a similar StackOverflow question: "[Customising Blackberry Treefield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992371/customising-blackberry-treefield/10145889#10145889)."

In that answer, I've re-drawn each row of a [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html) along with a [Bitmap](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html) image replacing the default (+)-icon of [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html).