# Parent Node or Child Node in Blackberry Tree Field?

Tags: blackberry, treeview, customization, treefield

I need to traverse a Tree Field in Blackberry .
I need to know how to check from the existing node whether it is a parent node or child node ?
Since I need a different row color for Child rows and Parent rows

I have referred a previous question of Customising TreeField as seen in link below

[Customising Blackberry Treefield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992371/customising-blackberry-treefield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're already using the `TreeFieldCallback` to customize painting of your tree field.  You can detect parent vs. child nodes here in [drawTreeItem()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeFieldCallback.html#drawTreeItem(net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TreeField,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

However, we need to be clear about what you consider "parent" and "child", because technically, it's possible for a row to be **both** a parent and a child, if the tree has more than 2 levels (in addition to the root level).

---

### If "Child" == "Leaf" Node

Use:

```java
public void drawTreeItem(TreeField treeField, Graphics graphics, int node, int y, int width, int indent)  {

    boolean isChild = treeField.getFirstChild(node) == -1;
    if (isChild) {
        // draw child row color
    } else { 
        // draw parent row color
    }
}
```

assuming that what you mean by "child" is a row that has no more children of its own (also called a "leaf" node).

---

### If "Child" == "Non-Root Parent"

If you consider a node that has both a non-root parent of its own **and** a child of its own to be a "child" row, then use this logic:

```java
public void drawTreeItem(TreeField treeField, Graphics graphics, int node, int y, int width, int indent)  {

    boolean isParent = treeField.getParent(node) == 0;
    if (isParent) {
        // draw parent row color
    } else { 
        // draw child row color
    }
}
```

this second implementation will only color rows that are **directly** under the root node as "parents".