# Parent & Child Node with different images & Clickable Event - Treeview Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am using tree view in app to show the client server data in blackberry. Same thing i achieved in android app by using expandable listview items. But here i'm facing two issues

### One is:

I want to add parent node icon like a folder icon & Child node must have different icon. For example if Parent item is images then child nodes must have Images icon, if parent item is video Then child have video icons.

### Second:

When i click on any child node (Like image child node), this node opens in new screen & shows the clickable item whether i click on image or video.

Here is my code that i used to Get the desired result:

```java
class CustomTreeFieldCallback implements TreeFieldCallback {
    public void drawTreeItem(TreeField _tree, Graphics g, int node, int y,
            int width, int indent) {
        // FontFamily
        FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
        Font font = fontFamily[1].getFont(FontFamily.CBTF_FONT, 18);
        g.setFont(font);
        String text = (String) _tree.getCookie(node);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("images.png");
        g.drawText(text, indent + b.getWidth(), y);
        g.drawBitmap(indent, y - 15, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), b, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

and

```java
public class FilesManager extends MainScreen {

    public FilesManager() {

        // Set the linear background.
        Bitmap background = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");
        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(background);
        this.getMainManager().setBackground(bg);

        String parentNode = new String("Images");
        String firstChild = new String("first child");
        String secondChild = new String("second child");
        String thirdChild = new String("third child");

        CustomTreeFieldCallback myCallback = new CustomTreeFieldCallback();
         myTree = new TreeField(myCallback, Field.FOCUSABLE); 

        int node2 = myTree.addChildNode(0, parentNode);
        myTree.addChildNode(node2, firstChild);
        myTree.addChildNode(node2, secondChild);
        myTree.addChildNode(node2, thirdChild);
        add(myTree);

    }

}
```

I also attached the screenShot that i made in android. Any one give me guideline to achieve this thing in BB?

[image]

Comment: Try looking [at this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9992371/119114).  You should be able to modify the answers provided to do what you want.  In `drawTreeItem()`, you need to check the `node` variable and draw different icons depending on which kind of node (parent/child) it is.

Comment: @Nate , I also try this answer before posting this answer. I am bit confused to add icon with parent node(in code images), bcz when i try to add icon with parent it implements on all node even its child or parent & vice versa.

Comment: Also when i add videos in treeview it has same parent icon like images but child must have different image like video icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are off to a good start.

To get the right icons, you just need to detect which tree "nodes" are folders, movies, songs, images, etc.  Do that either with `TreeField#getFirstChild()` or by checking the cookie/text, for each node, inside `drawTreeItem()`.

To handle clicks on the movie, image, or song rows, [override `navigationClick()`](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/TreeField-and-navigationClick-for-expand-collapse/td-p/284795).

For example, starting with [the TreeFieldDemo from BlackBerry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Tree_field_1204072_11.jsp):

```java
class TreeFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{

   private final Bitmap openIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("folder-open.png");
   private final Bitmap closedIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("folder-closed.png");
   private final Bitmap movieIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("movie.png");
   private final Bitmap songIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("song.png");
   private final Bitmap playIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("play.png");

   public TreeFieldDemoScreen()
   {             
      setTitle("Tree Field Demo");

      TreeCallback myCallback = new TreeCallback();
      TreeField myTree = new TreeField(myCallback, Field.FOCUSABLE) {
         protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            // We'll only override unvarnished navigation click behavior
            if ((status & KeypadListener.STATUS_ALT) == 0 &&
                  (status & KeypadListener.STATUS_SHIFT) == 0)
            {
               final int node = getCurrentNode();
               if (getFirstChild(node) == -1) {               
                  // Click is on a leaf node. Do some default action or else fall through.                  

                  // Note:  this will also detect empty folders, which might or 
                  //  might not be something your app has to handle
                  Dialog.alert("clicked " + getCookie(node));
                  // TODO: open player screen, etc.   
                  return true;              
               }
            }
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
         }
      };

      myTree.setDefaultExpanded(false);
      myTree.setRowHeight(openIcon.getHeight());

      String nodeOne = new String("Video");  // folder
      String nodeTwo = new String("Music");  // folder
      String nodeThree = new String("Images"); // folder
      String nodeFour = new String("song.mp3");
      String nodeFive = new String("movie.m4v");

      int node1 = myTree.addChildNode(0, nodeOne);
      int node2 = myTree.addChildNode(0, nodeTwo);
      int node3 = myTree.addChildNode(0, nodeThree);
      int node4 = myTree.addChildNode(node2, nodeFour);
      int node5 = myTree.addChildNode(node1, nodeFive);

      add(myTree);
   }


   private class TreeCallback implements TreeFieldCallback 
   {
      public void drawTreeItem(TreeField _tree, Graphics g, int node, int y, int width, int indent) 
      {
         final int PAD = 8;
         String text = (String)_tree.getCookie(node);
         Bitmap icon = closedIcon;
         if (text.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            icon = songIcon;
         } else if (text.endsWith(".m4v")) {
            icon = movieIcon;
         } else if (_tree.getExpanded(node)) {
            icon = openIcon;
         }
         g.drawBitmap(indent, y, icon.getWidth(), icon.getHeight(), icon, 0, 0);
         // This assumes filenames all contain '.' character!
         if (text.indexOf(".") > 0) {
            // Leaf node, so this is a playable item (movie or song)
            g.drawBitmap(_tree.getWidth() - playIcon.getWidth() - PAD, y + PAD, 
                  playIcon.getWidth(), playIcon.getHeight(), playIcon, 0, 0);
         }
         int fontHeight = getFont().getHeight();
         g.drawText(text, indent + icon.getWidth() + PAD, y + (_tree.getRowHeight() - fontHeight)/2);
      }
   }
}
```

My navigation click handler is coded to accept clicks on the entire movie or song row, not just the "play" button itself.  I think this is easier on touch devices, since the user's finger doesn't have to hit a small touch target.  You can change this if you like, though.

### Results

[image]

**Note:** I didn't bother to hook up an icon for image files ... you should be able to do that now.