# How to create expandable listview in blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, expandablelistview

i search a lot but no single link found for Expandable listview in Blackberry, i know how to create Expandable list in android ,if someone having idea about Blackberry Expandable listview than please help me.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify two things (1) are you developing for BB10 or BB7 and (2) when you say expand, do you mean that the entries expand, or that the number of rows in the list expands.

Comment: see above something like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customising Blackberry Treefield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992371/customising-blackberry-treefield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean BlackBerry Java SDK, then take a look at [TreeField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html) class.

**UPDATE:**

In this case the [ListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html) would be the most suitable choice. Implement [ListFieldCallback](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListFieldCallback.html) according to your needs and attach it to the ListField instance. When user clicks on an "expandable" list item, then just process this event in ListFieldCallback and repaint your list instance. Here is [the tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=898) on working with ListField classes.

Comment: i want to create view view on listview which is having sublist see above image

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to create List on BB is to use the ListField class.  This class is extremely efficient but has a couple of drawbacks

- All the rows have to be the same height
- All the rows have to contiguous on the display

This makes it difficult to use this class to replicate the Android ExpandingListView.

To replicate this look on a BlackBerry device, I suggest a series of VerticalFieldManagers (VFMs).  Use one for the whole list, and add to this another for each expandable item.  If the item is expanded, add child list entries to the associated VFM, when not expanded, delete the child entries.

This approach will work OK up to a point - adding and removing Fields can slow down the BB device significantly if there are significant number of Fields on display.  So if you have, say 20 items in the list, then it will be fine.  If you have 2000, it will slow the device down significantly when you expand and contract the list (add and remove the child list items).

You can improve this performance, by making your list items (parent and child) as efficient as possible. I recommend reviewing the code that is used for the ListStyleButtonField that you will find here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

**Update**

Just wanted to clarify why ListField does not work directly, and a possible work around.

The problem with ListField is each row has a specific height.  To display the child elements you really need to expand the height of the parent item to include the children, which you can't do.  So you can't just update the called back paint method (called drawListRow(..) in a ListField) to achieve this look.  And the other problem, is that one list item on a ListField is focused as a single entity where as I assume you would want to select the children individually.

Instead, when expanding you can add additional rows, effectively inserting the children items in the list to be drawn.  You will have to add these rows with a flag, so that your drawListRow(..) method knows to paint these as children.  Reverse on deletion.  Note that the children items have to be the same height as everything else.

Having attempted both, I have found the VFM approach easier to manage.  I would only consider the ListField approach where the list was large enough to impact performance.  And when it is that large, who is going to scroll through that number of entries on their BB?  If you are getting to that number, then a paging mechanism would seem more user friendly.